# Struts <bean:write> tags

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

How do I escape character like '&' in struts  tags. For example we can mention.

```
<a href="./testaction.do?testmethod=bookResult&bookTitle=<bean:write name="booklist" property="title"/>" class="nLink"><bean:write name="booklist" property="title"/></a></small>
```

I'm iteration over a book list array (booklist) and setting book titles one by one.In this scenario I need to escape characters like '&' within the 'title' property in order execute the respective logic for that particular action.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe use the `filter` attribute?

```
<bean:write name="booklist" property="title" filter="true" />
```

More on [`<bean:write>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-bean.html#write). The documentation states:

> If this attribute is set to `true`,
>   the rendered property value will be
>   filtered for characters that are
>   sensitive in HTML, and any such
>   characters will be replaced by their
>   entity equivalents.

Comment: I think it's only for rendering purposes.The actual value passed to the server side is not get filtered.

Comment: It's only for rendering purposes, as you've said....the actual value is never changes from presentation layer to controller and vice versa.

Comment: In some book titles, the problem is when '&' came the url mapper thinks it as another parameter so the book title get splitted in to two words and the action is not get executed.

Comment: If `filter` doesn't work (which is strange, as it works for me everytime), replace `&` with `&amp;` before sending it to a request.

Comment: consider this: http://server-user/actions/testaction.do?testmethod=bookResult&bookTitle=COMPUTER & WINDOWS 2095

Comment: then it will not work properly because the '&', thinks it as a new parameter.

Comment: Hence I said, *before* you use `bookList.title`, convert the String using `String.replace("&", "&amp;");` and return to the result to the jsp. Alternatively, create a new bean called `htmlEditedTitle` and replace your `title` with `htmlEditedTitle`. The `htmlEditedTitle` will be the edited String that does the `&` conversion.

Comment: Sweet, Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you want to show the book title on URL bar (or use it in the URL).
And some of the book title is having '&' in their title.
If so? you have to replace it with '%26'.
Replace this in the action where you are setting the collection.
If you are fetching it from DB, then replace it in sql query.