# What is equivalent Struts 1.3 tags for <s:property value="Content" escapeHtml="false" />

Tags: java, html, struts2, struts, struts-1

I want equivalent Struts 1.3 tag for `<s:property value="Content" escapeHtml="false" />`

Currently I am trying something like   `<bean:write  name="MyForm" property="Content" filter="false" ></bean:write>`

I want to hide/remove HTML tags from My Content - I am having data from CKEditor which is combination of HTML tags.

Comment: Many people uses Struts 1.x, Andrea you can't make comment like this. If you don't know answer don't comment. Moderators please make not of this

Comment: Many people are wrong, and on their on, since [Struts1 is EOL](https://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html) (since years). BTW can't you simply [use JSP EL to print the value unescaped ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23367430/1654265)

Comment: It Worekd for me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397648/struts-beanwrite-tags

Comment: @CodeHungry It's a harmless, amusing comment; relax. Everybody knows that sometimes developers work within unfortunate constraints.

Comment: A lot of people used Struts 1, and still continue to use, but Struts 1 no longer supported from Apache, so if you find a bug in Struts1 you have to fix it yourself. If you want a new feature, you have to develop it yourself. Everything else is running as expected that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `bean:write` tag you can output the value from the action form property. If you want to use a scope variable, you can use JSP EL or JSTL `c:out`

```
${MyForm.Content} or    
<c:out value="${MyForm.Content}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me for removing escape characters from CkEditor get Data function [Bean:write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397648/struts-beanwrite-tags)

Comment: If it's a dupe, mark it as a dupe, otherwise include actionable information in the answer itself.